# What does a limit without anything underneath it mean?

Tags: limits, functions

In an exercise you're asked to find the limit of a function, but there's no x→a or anything similar under the expression lim f(x), so wheres the x tending to?

[image: image from exercise]

Comment: Most probably, $n\to\infty$. That's the typical limit of a sequence.

Comment: Can you provide more details on $x_n$ and $f$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience I'll assume we are dealing with a function $f$ from real numbers to real numbers.
It is reasonable to guess the meaning as below:

A sequence of real  numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ is given.

This function is applied to (or evaluated at) each term of the sequence, yielding a new sequence of function values:

$f(x_1), f(x_2), f(x_3),\ldots$

So the limit in your question refers to the limit of the sequence in the last line above.
Symbolically $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$$

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a limit with nothing underneath it is completely nonsensical. There may be some context provided that might help, for example the basis of the question, but if there's nothing, it's most likely to be infinity. Otherwise, this doesn't make any actual sense.